# How is QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES enforced?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-11

Android 11 (target 30) introduces [Package visibility restrictions](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/package-visibility).

They added the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES that allows bypassing these restrictions, and only specific apps are allowed to use it.

The protection level for this permission is NORMAL, and so I wondered how limiting this permission is enforced.

In the documentation, they say:

> In an upcoming policy update, look for Google Play to provide
> guidelines for apps that need the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission.

Does anyone know where this policy update can be found?

Comment: if this permission is `NORMAL`, then when declared in manifest is granted automatically during package installation. but now it will be visible "somewhere" - maybe on the list of all perms in Google Play, maybe in apps system Settings, maybe possible to revoke from there... yeah, hidden as much as possible, but still is and you may know which app is profiling you by your installed app scanning. in fact most of users won't notice and I bet this is intended: now this isn't some "hidden and powerful API", but all app developers can still use it for e.g. suggesting more acurate ads

Comment: What you are describing is very weak (to no) enforcement. I think that it will be enforced via the policy update mentioned in the documentation. I was just wondering if someone saw it :)

Answer (score 0):

QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission has a normal protection level so it doesn't throw an exception when added.

The way I enforce this permission is by calling `queryUsageStats` on a `UsageStatsManager` instance. If it returns an empty list, I notify the user to turn on Usage Data Access in phone Settings.

```
private fun requestPackagePermission() {
        val stats: List<UsageStats> = usageStatsManager
            .queryUsageStats(
                UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_BEST,
                0,
                System.currentTimeMillis()
            )
        val isEmpty = stats.isEmpty()
        if (isEmpty) {
            // notify user before opening app settings
            startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS))
        } else {
            // carry out your work
        }
    }
```

I call this method in `onResume()` of my activity or fragment so that when Usage Data Access is turned on and the user navigates back to the app, the method is called again in order to confirm the change.